# Change Button Text After Validating Fields Are Completed

Tags: javascript

My form includes a search that takes about 10 seconds. The submit button is titled SEARCH and upon clicking I have set this up to change to SEARCHING. This is the code:

```
<input type=submit class=button 
value=&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
onclick="javascript:formSubmit();this.value='Searching...'">
```

But now I need to validate that an email field and another field are completed so that the button text changes to SEARCHING ***only*** if validated.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
<input type=submit class=button 
value=&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
onclick="myFunction();javascript:formSubmit();this.value='Searching...'">

<script>
function myFunction() {
  if ( document.getElementsByName('numberadults')[0].value == '0' )
    alert('The number of adults must be more than zero!');   
  document.getElementById("myEmail").required = true;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The required property was set. The email field must now be filled out before submitting the form.";
}
</script>
```

Here is the html of the two fields being validated:

```
<select name=numberadults class=cboStyleZ>
<option value=0 selected>
0
</option>
<option value=1>
1
</option>
<option value=2>
2
</option>
<option value=3>
3
</option>
<option value=4>
4
</option>
<option value=5>
5
</option>
<option value=6>
6
</option>
<option value=--->
---
</option>
</select>

<input type="email" id="myEmail" class=cboStyleZ1 name="eaddr" 
placeholder="Your email is all we need">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
//other statements if required

document.getElementById("search").value = "searching";


}
</script>
<input type=submit class=button id="search"
value="search"; 
onclick="myFunction()">
```

I think this code can help you

Answer (score 0):

The following click handler:

```
onclick="myFunction();javascript:formSubmit();this.value='Searching...'"
```

doesn't indicate how the validation in `myFunction` would affect the form submission and the text change.
There are several ways to skin a cat here, but in general, you could rely on control structures like `if` or using short-circuit operators to change the execution flow based on the value of an expression that interests you (e.g.: the return value of `myFunction()`)

**HTML**

```
onclick="if(myFunction()) { javascript:formSubmit();this.value='Searching...'} "
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
    if ( document.getElementsByName('numberadults')[0].value == '0' ) {
        // ...
        // Display what is wrong with the form to the user
        // ...
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```